# How to generate links to images using php in a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a table that will display the new suggested products by users to allow a moderator to to choose which get approved. For now, all I am trying to do is show the image, as well as the user that submitted it and some other info. I know my problem is with the bottom echo statement that tries to put together a working url by combining the file location and the name of the file itself from the database, which is stored like "Roots.jpg" or like "brock.jpg"
Thanks for any help. I am pretty new to php.

```
<html>
<title>Forum Approval</title>
<body>

    <?php

$db_host = "host";
$db_username = "user";
$db_pass = "pass";
$db_name = "name";
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM add_new_product";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    ?>

    <table border='1' align='center'>
        <caption>Products to approve</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Id</th>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['new_prod_ID'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['user_ID'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['company'] . '</td>';
            echo "<td><img src = "a link/uploads/ . $row['image']"  .  width='100'></td>";
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the echo to something like...

```
echo "<td><img src=\"path/to/directory/".$row['image']."\" width='100'></td>
```

The src would be `path/to/directory/Roots.jpg`